# Android and Protobuf

Tags: java, android, sdk, protocol-buffers

i use android sdk 2.1, and protobuf 2.4.1

this is my .proto file:

```
package com.example.proto;

option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;

message DatabaseInsertRequest {
  optional string stringInsert = 1;
}

message DatabaseSelectRequest {
  optional string stringSelect = 1;
}

message DatabaseUpdateRequest {
  optional string stringUpdate = 1;
}
```

i compiled this .proto to class (using protoc)

after i try send this message with socket and got a error, (forget it)
may you please show me working example ?

Comment: please provide the error

Answer (score 3):

have a look at the documentation!

[JavaTutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html)

Comment: yes, i got this tutorial, but it work on java, but not work in android

Comment: the protobuf-code is working fine. The only thing is the general program: main-function with args and file-read/write. Try to write to a file on the sd-card and try to trigger the write-operations on a button-click-event in an activity (for testing purpose)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void writeData() {
    long startTime;
    long totalTime;
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Constants.mSereverUrl + Constants.PORT + Constants.ContactRequest);
    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(toBytes));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
        totalTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        if (mCurrentMode == PROTO_MODE) {
            Constants.setProtoPostTime(totalTime);
        } else if (mCurrentMode == JSON_MODE) {
            Constants.setJsonPostTime(totalTime);
        }
        System.out.println("Request data sent");
        System.out.println("Response Code :: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Above is the code snippet from my sample code for ProtoBuf integration with Android. Let me know if you need further help.